# Adobe Air iOS Invalid Bundle The bundle does not support the minimum version os specified in info.plist

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I got this error and thought I'd share the answer, as it was only due to years of Adobe Air for iOS development I could solve the problem. :)

If you, when uploading through Application Loader get an error like:

```
Invalid Bundle The bundle does not support the minimum version os specified in info.plist
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simple add

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
```

into your AppName-app.xml manifest into "InfoAdditions" section.

This was the first thing I've tried. But this didn't help me to get rid of this error...

UPD: Just found [here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/error-itms-9000-invalid-bundle-the-bundle-my-app-app-does-not-support-the-minimum-os-version-specified-in-the-56qwo):

> Hi,everyone.
>
> I have the same warning too.   But I was just resolved.
>
> As a result of the update to the latest version of Mac OSX(10.9.5)
>   that is installed in the Application loader, it came to success.
>
> I don't know this reason.   Please try.

Can anybody check if this really helps? Also it would be good to check both cases - with default MinimumOSVersion and with set to 6.0 (for example).

Comment: I've updated to Mac OSX 10.9.5 and the failure to occur.

Comment: I updated the min version to 6 and also updated application loader to version 3 , i still get the error.

Answer (score 7):

To solve the issue you should add

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>6.1</string>
```

(or higher)
AND
make sure the **extensions you use have the same (or higher) MinimumOSVersion value** in theirs manifests!
If no - you should update extensions or "hack" a bit their manifests.

I use latest release AIR SDK.

UPD: Latest AIR SDK Beta fixes loader error "Invalid Segment Alignment"

Answer (score 1):

To solve (on Mac OS X):

- Rename myapp.ipa to myapp.zip
- Unzip
- Go to the created "Payload" folder
- Right click myapp.app and click "Show package content"
- Open info.plist in a text editor
- Change the value string of MinimumOSVersion to (at least this is what I put in, and it works)

  `<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>`
- Save the file and exit
- Right click the Payload folder and click "Compress 'Payload'"
- Rename back Payload.zip to myapp.ipa (where myapp is the original name of your ipa)

You have now solved this problem, however you may get an error when uploading, that the code signing is not messed up. I could upload OK but then when I went to the Prelaunch section of itunesconnect, it said "Invalid Binary" after 15 minutes.

In this case, also complete the following steps:

- Create a file called Entitlements.plist in the same folder as your ipa, with the following content:

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>application-identifier</key>
      <string>XXXXXXXX.com.my.app</string>
      <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
      <array>
          <string>XXXXXXXX.com.my.app</string>
      </array>
  </dict>
  </plist>`

Where XXXXXXXX is your team(?) code in your Distribution Certificate KeyChain Access, and com.my.app is your app's app ID.

Then run the following code in the terminal
    `/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: MyName Surname (XXXXXXXX)" "--resource-rules=./Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "Entitlements.plist" "./Payload/MyApp.app"`

These steps should of course be taken before the last two steps above :)

UPLOAD and it should work!

Comment: You changed your MinimumOSVersion to 6.0, what was it set to before?  Mine is set to 7.0 and that's where I'd like to keep it.  Is this problem something specific to using MinimumOSVersion other than 6.0?

Comment: John Watson, by default AIR compiler sets MinimumOSVersion to 4.3

Comment: @DenisMaslov My application descriptor has MinimumOSVersion set to 7.0.  The compiled IPA info.plist also has the correct MinimumOSVersion.  The error persists.  "ERROR ITMS-9000: Invalid Bundle. The bundle 'XXX' does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist.".  How do I find out more information about what OS Version _IS_ supported by my bundle?

Comment: This solution may work but it is really hard and error prune. See @Denis Maslov solution for much easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

I updated macosx to 10.9.5 and also changed my infoadditions on application xml to:

```
<InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
```

After that, the application loader uploaded my ipa with no errors.